# Custom ListView with animated visibility toggle

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-animation

I have a Custom Listview with a lot of text in it.. I'd like that when I click on the the ListView other text will appear under the clicked row.. I managed to do this set the TextView to GONE in the custom_row.xml and then in the ClickListener set it to VISIBLE.. But this is too glitching and so I'd like to make a toggle animation like [JQUERY](http://jqueryui.com/show/#default)'s blind show...

[image]

How can I make this with an animation in Android ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Animation and change height of item, like:

```
public class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
...
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
       super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
            viewLayoutParams.height = heightStart + 
                    (int) (( heightEnd - heightStart) * interpolatedTime);
            animatedView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

And set this animation on item when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) to change the height of ListView from 0 to final height.

You can find a very good example [in this tutorial](http://gmariotti.blogspot.in/2013/09/expand-and-collapse-animation.html)

The code would be as follows:

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(intialHeight, finalHeight);    
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator v) {
        int value = (Integer) v.getAnimatedValue(); // get the most recent value calculated by the ValueAnimator 
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = yourLayout.getLayoutParams(); // get the height of your ListView
        lp.height = value; //change the height
        mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams); //update it to the view
    }   
animator.start(); //start the animation
```